# Azure Devops default Microsoft-hosted agent pool is missing

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Do you have any ideas how to reactivate the microsoft hosted agent pool?
Look at the image, from my dashboard it is missing "Azure Pipelines".
(I use the free Version of Azure Devops)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a change made earlier this year to prevent abuse by crypto miners; you no longer get pipelines automatically in new organizations, you have to specifically request that they be enabled.

> By default, new organizations created in Azure DevOps will no longer get a free grant of concurrent pipelines. This applies to both public as well as private projects in new organizations.
> To request your free grant, send an email to azpipelines-freetier@microsoft.com and provide the following details clearly:
>
> - Your name
> - Azure DevOps organization for which you are requesting the free grant
> - Whether you need the free grant for public projects, private projects, or both
> - Links to the repositories that you plan to build (public projects only)
> - Brief description of your project (public projects only)

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/pipelines/sprint-184-update#changes-to-azure-pipelines-free-grants